# Predict different values from same inputs in a linear regressor model?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Let's suppose I have a noisy 2d data set where one person watching the data could easily draw a straight line in the data so that the mean squared error is minimized.

The model of the line has the form `y = mx + b`, where `x` is the input value, `y` is the predicted value of the model and `m` and `b` are trained variables to minimize the cost.

My question is that if we plug some input `x1` to the model, it will always output the same number, not taking into account how sparse the data is. How can a model like this predict different values from same inputs?

Maybe this could be done taking all the errors from the model line to the points, making a distribution of them, taking an expected value of such distribution and then adding that value to `y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is 2d, and it can be perfectly modeled with a straight line then there is no data-based nor statistical-based reason not to claim that the process is fully deterministic, and you **should** output one value.

However, if you have many more dimensions, or your fit is not perfect (error is minimised but not 0) then what you are after is either predicting **distribution** of values or at least **confidence bounds**. There are many probabilistic models that can model distribution of the outputs rather than a singe value. In particular linear regression does that, it assumes that you have a Gaussian error around your predictions, thus effectively once you obtain MSE "A" you can draw predictions from N(mx+b, A) - which, as you can easily see degenerates to deterministic model when A=0. These predictions are optimal in expectation, and they are simply your way of "simulating observations" according to the model. There are also meta methods, if you treat your predictor as a black box - you can train multiple models on subsets of data, and treat their predictions as samples to fit a distribution (again for simplicity it could be a single Gaussian).